# guard-livereload not reload browser

Tags: php, ruby, guard, livereload

I am using `guard-livereload` gem to monitor changes in a PHP project. This is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/cristianogregnanin/2add0da3a838edf950ac#file-guard-livereload) to describe my guard config:

```
#setup the Gemfile
$ nano Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
group :development do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
end

$ bundle

#config the Guardfile
$ nano Guardfile
guard :livereload do
  watch(%r{.+\.(css|js|html|php|tpl)$})
end
```

When I run `guard` it works same but the browser don't reload the page.

```
$ bundle exec guard
18:37:36 - INFO - Guard is using NotifySend to send notifications.
18:37:36 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
18:37:36 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
18:37:36 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/var/www/html/se/se/application/modules/Tmp'
[1] guard(main)> 18:37:43 - INFO - Browser connected.
18:37:54 - INFO - Reloading browser: views/scripts/tmp/index.tpl
18:38:02 - INFO - Reloading browser: views/scripts/tmp/index.tpl
18:38:12 - INFO - Reloading browser: views/scripts/tmp/index.tpl
18:38:23 - INFO - Reloading browser: views/scripts/tmp/index.tpl
[1] guard(main)>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your html source contains, in header, lines like this : `<script type="text/javascript">
  RACK_LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?"></script>`. If not, sure, it will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reloading seems to be triggered properly, your problem is likely on the browser side. You need to

- [Install the browser extension](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86242-how-do-i-install-and-use-the-browser-extensions)
- Run `bundle exec guard` in your shell
- Navigate to your app in the browser
- Activate Live Reload by clicking on its icon

[image: Live Reload Icon]